# Import & export database with all data in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, asp.net-web-api, ssms-2012

I need to import a SQL Server database from SQL Server Management Studio. I'm using SSMS 18 for both the end.

I want to export the whole database with all tables, columns, data and import with same. I tried few ways but that didn't help me.

Hope will get better solution with understandable steps.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do that at all? If you want to transfer everything just take a backup and restore it to another server. It's 100+ times faster than scripting, taking far less space. Backup is an online operation too, which means there's no downtime. You can also compress backups, reducing the size *and* IO required

Comment: If you want this for development/version control purposes, you can [export a data-tier application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/export-a-data-tier-application?view=sql-server-ver15) and create either a `bacpac` that contains both schema and data or a `dacpac` that contains the schema only. A `dacpac` can be used to generate differences between databases and deploy changes. Visual Studio's Data Tools can diff a database against a dacpac, or generate a database project from a dacpac

Answer (score 4):

As [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos) said, it's better to take a backup and restore it. Sometimes because of version difference it can't be done. So the other way is generating scripts of all objects and data.

Follow below steps:

Step 1: Open SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

Step 2: Select the database to script.

Step 3: Right-click on the database and select Tasks > Generate Scripts.

Step 4: On the Choose Objects page, leave the default selection of ’Script entire database and all database objects’ selected

Step 5: On the ’Specify how scripts should be saved or published’ page, click the Advanced button

Step 6: The last selection in the General properties group is ’Types of data to script’, change this to ’Schema and data’

Step 7: If you know you are sending this to someone with an older SQL Server version, you can change the ’Script for Server Version’ property to the Server version you need.

Step 8: If you have triggers in your database, set 'Script Trigger' property true.

Step 9: Click Ok.

Step 10: Change the file location or wherever you want to script to be generated.

Step 11: Click Next, the Next again. At this point, the script will be generated.

Thanks to [Dennis Piccioni](https://www.dataaccess.com/blog/systems-environments/sharing-sql-server-databases-via-scripting-1336)

Comment: If your database contains foreign keys, you are going to have errors while importing the data, because of the incorrect table import order.

Comment: Thanks Iman. I don't recall it being hidden this well in previous versions of ssms.

"Step 5: On the ’Specify how scripts should be saved or published’ page, click the Advanced button
Step 6: The last selection in the General properties group is ’Types of data to script’, change this to ’Schema and data’"